# libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast error on AmazonEC2 with Ubuntu14

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, graphics-processing-unit

I have a `t2.large` instance on `Amazon EC2` with `8Go` of ram and `30Go` of disk space.

The OS used is `Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty` and the desktop manager is `xfce4`. I'm using `xrdp` to remotely access the desktop, and it is working relatively well.

However, I have issues with some `GUI` applications, the error I get is:

`libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

The graphic card is:

```sh
$ lshw -C video+
*-display UNCLAIMED
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: GD 5446
    vendor: Cirrus Logic
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 00
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: vga_controller bus_master
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:f0000000-f1ffffff memory:f3000000-f3000fff
```

And I cannot find the driver for this graphic card (Cirrus Logic).

Is it possible to change the `Graphic card` with `AmazonEC2`? Or is there a `universal driver` for all graphic cards on `Ubuntu`?

Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Cheking the result of an `image processing` algorithm without having to download the `output image` each time to my laptop.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelHampton, I'm trying to apply algorithms on `Satellite images` so they're quiet large (to download) using `Sentinel toolboxes` (http://step.esa.int/main/toolboxes/snap/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software you are running is trying to use OpenGL, but the virtual hardware is not OpenGL-capable. The virtual machine emulates a mid-1990's Cirrus video card which is barely capable of displaying graphics at all.

In order to run software that requires OpenGL on Amazon EC2, you must use a GPU (G2 or CG1) instance.

Considering that this may be significantly more expensive than the instance you are using now, you may wish to simply continue downloading images to check them as you are now.